# How to design table or collection for storing destinations?

Tags: sql, database, mongodb

I have an task to store data about destinations of delivery, where companies can ship the postal parcel.

The trivial way is to create a table

```
CompanyShippmentPlaces

    id | country | city
```

There are the some design issues:

1. What if need be delivered to towns or villages, not to cities? That means altering a table?
2. What if company needs to specify a part of city, townm or village?
3. What if the destinations have the same name?

**How I plan to use this data:**

When system gest a order, the order should be distributes across all companies. I must get all companies that can deliver this product.

It pushes me to use noSQL database, but I am not confident.

What do you think about that?

Comment: This is not a problem you're facing. Please avoid asking opinion based questions.

Comment: Where can I do it,to ask opition and recommendations?

Comment: If you have option to use mongodb , use it. It is more user friendly for json and can be easily flexible as per use case

Comment: Yep, NoSQL is generally quite flexible for many use cases, including yours. It doesn't need you to define a schema per say.

Comment: What about storing coordinates of places? City has borders and company can specify zones where shipment is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What if need be delivered to towns or villages, not to cities? That means altering a table?**
This would be solved by the solution of jaimish11.
Peronsaly I would change the naming of "City" to "locality" (or something comparable - to generalize).

**What if company needs to specify a part of city, townm or village?**
I think this is solved by the address lines.

**What if the destinations have the same name?**
Normaly (as much that i know) each location in a country has it's own pin- or zipcode respectively if the naming doesn't match the post will use the code to identify the location. (to be sure you should ask the post in your at least in your country)

**When system gest a order, the order should be distributes across all companies. I must get all companies that can deliver this product.**

I would get all locations where the products are available and then get the location wich is next by the city out of the first selection. Maybe you could save the nearest location to a city in your "city table".

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're describing isn't actually an issue. No matter what database you use (SQL or NoSQL) you can simply have all the address fields you need such as:

Address Line 1 
Address Line 2
Landmark
City
Pincode/ Zipcode
State
Country

This way, it won't matter whether it's city, town or village.